# How to solve unchecked cast

Tags: java, enums

I am trying to setget the ENUM value of a class' ENUM field. "value" is actually a string value read from file. Retrieving, but retrieving it as below throws me an unchecked cast warning:

```
Object value = "BAR";
Field field = Test.class.getField("bar");

if (field.getType().isEnum()) {
   value = Enum.valueOf((Class<Enum>) field.getType(), (String) value);
   Test test = new Test();
   field.set(test, value);                  
}

...

public class Test {
   public Foo bar;
}

...

public enum Foo {
   BAR;
}
```

The warning is clear, but I am confused how to address/solve this warning, any thoughts?

```
[unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method valueOf in class Enum is applied to given types
  required: Class<T>,String
  found:    Class<Enum>,String
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Enum<T> declared in method <T>valueOf(Class<T>,String)
```

Comment: What is the type of `getType()`? And why isn’t it `Class<T extends Enum>`? It would be better to invoke the actual Enum class’s `valueOf()` method directly.

Comment: It's warning. You're doing reflection, warnings are inevitable. Find a less finicky way to do whatever it is you are doing (can't advise you there, the question does not include enough detail), or, accept the warning. You can stick a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation on the method this code is in, if you want.